# Inserting double quotes into mysql and printing them out without backslashes

Tags: php, mysql, echo, backslash, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a form where the following type of code must be inserted:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3035.058400512634!2d-3.6438669999999997!3d40.473973!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd422eea55d33c51%3A0x3294408e8e67eff4!2sClinica+Dental+Artidental!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1419779677798" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

I am catching the posted value as follows:

```
$mapLink = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mapLink'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

And the iframe is inserted as follows:

```
&lt;iframe src=\&quot;https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3035.058400512634!2d-3.6438669999999997!3d40.473973!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd422eea55d33c51%3A0x3294408e8e67eff4!2sClinica+Dental+Artidental!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1419779677798\&quot; width=\&quot;600\&quot; height=\&quot;450\&quot; frameborder=\&quot;0\&quot; style=\&quot;border:0\&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

How can I do in order to fetch back my initial link `"<iframe src..."` with php and print it out as it was written initially? Without the backslashes, &quot, etc

**UPDATE 1**

Here is how I insert/update in MYSQL:

```
            $editCentro = $con->prepare("UPDATE centros SET  active = :active, nombre = :nombre, zona = :zona, address = :address,
        metro = :metro, zip = :zip, phone = :phone, fax = :fax, email = :email, mapLink = :mapLink, descripcion = :descripcion, horarios = :horarios
        WHERE id = ".$centroId);
        $editCentro->execute(array(':active'=>$active, ':nombre'=> $nombre, ':zona'=>$zona, ':address'=>$address, ':metro'=>$metro, 
        ':zip'=>$zip, ':phone'=>$telefono, ':fax'=>$fax, ':email'=>$email, ':mapLink'=>$mapLink, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion, ':horarios'=>$horarios));
```

And even when not escaping the value, it gets inserted with a backslash before the double quotes...

Comment: Why are you escaping it in the first place if you need the original value? `htmlspecialchars` isn't meant for database quoting.

Comment: You need to understanding what escaping actually means.  You then need to disable magic quotes.

Comment: @mario I escape because otherwise the double quotes mess up with my PHP and halt the insertion truncating the whole value

Comment: We already concluded that you're doing something wrong elsewhere. And now you're looking for the wrong workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You escape the string when assigning it to `$mapLink`:

```php
$mapLink = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mapLink'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

If you want to insert it to the database as-is, simply take the value from post, and *don't* escape it. (Also, that's not the escaping you would use to prevent SQLi)

To prevent SQL injection, use mysql binding like so:

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO sometable (fieldA, mapField, fieldC) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $someVar, $mapLink, $otherVar);
```

See more info on parameter binding [in the PHP docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

If you have problems with magic quotes, you can strip them like so:

```php
$mapLink = stripslashes($_POST['mapLink']);
```

Comment: When I insert directly in the database, it comes out with backslashes before the double quotes.... And I am preparing and executing with an array

Comment: @samyb8 Please post the code that you use to insert it to the database. If you bind a value from `$_POST['mapLink']` with no modifications, backslashes shouldn't be there.

Comment: @samyb8 I'm no expert in PDO (I've mainly used mysqli) but could you `var_dump($mapLink)` just before inserting to see if the string is received escaped or it happens when inserting?

Comment: @samyb8 Also, if you are using PHP 5.4 or previous, it may be caused by "magic quotes". I've added how to remove them to my answer.

Comment: Magic quotes was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)?

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```